# Spring Security @PreAuthorize not seeing Role on incoming Request

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-rest

As stated in the title, I am currently in the process of creating a REST API, using Spring Security to create a Role System for handling the protection of Endpoints. For this I use the @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SOMEROLEHERE')") method, however it does not seem to recognize the roles from any request I have tried.

Below I will share some of the related code, hopefully someone can help me understand what is going wrong. If more code is required to see what might be wrong, I'll make sure to add it. Much appreciation in advance!

**License Controller**

```
    @PostMapping("/create-license")
    public void createAccount(@RequestBody License licenseToCreate)
    {
        licenseRepository.save(licenseToCreate);
    }
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(IUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ApplicationUser foundApplicationUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (foundApplicationUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new User(foundApplicationUser.getUsername(), foundApplicationUser.getPassword(), getAuthority(foundApplicationUser));
    }

    private Set getAuthority(ApplicationUser user) {
        Set authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRoles().getRoleName()));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: hasRole('ROLE_SOMEROLEHERE') is redundant. Try removing ROLE_ so it reads hasRole('SOMEROLEHERE')

Comment: @RobWinch Tried to alter it like you suggested but currently I still get a 403 Forbidden response, even though I have a valid JWT with the correct role

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to replace `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SOMEROLEHERE')")` with  `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_SOMEROLEHERE')")`?

Because in *UserDetailsServiceImpl* it looks like you're assigning authorities to the user.